# Java Histogram from three one dimensional arrays

Tags: java, graph, plot, histogram

I have three one dimensional arrays with RGB values of an image.

```
    int[] rhistogram = new int[256];
    int[] ghistogram = new int[256];
    int[] bhistogram = new int[256];
```

I need to plot them in a histogram. The histogram may be plotted in a swing frame or just in console with "*" symbols like that. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of plot are you talking about? Inside an application? Desktop, mobile or web? Dynamic or static data? You can make a plot in a spreadsheet, but I doubt that's what you're asking. You need to be more specific.

Comment: hi wolfcastle, thanks for response. Any plotting mechanism would do. Let it be console output with "*" or in a swing frame.

Answer (score 0):

[JFreeChart makes nice swing graphs](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html). They have a web-start demo so you can see all of the different charts they make. It might be overkill for what you want to do, however.

What about just writing the values to a CSV file, and importing it into a spreadsheet and plotting it there?